# Export Eclipse Preferences from the Command Line

Tags: eclipse

How do you export your Eclipse preferences from the command line? I know how to do it using the UI, via File->Export->Preferences, but I want to setup a cron job to back this up weekly.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to copy all of the settings from .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings if you're just wanting to create a backup of your settings.  If you actually need the epf format, then you could try something like [this article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21273017) does and execute a headless Eclipse that exports the preferences.

```
IPreferencesService service = org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform
.getPreferencesService();

service.exportPreferences(service.getRootNode(),
 new FileOutputStream(new File(this.getPreferencesFile())),
 null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this before, but I would think that all of the preferences are stored under ${eclipse_home}/configuration or workspace/.metadata

try `find ./ | xargs egrep 'prop1|prop2|...|propN'` from your configuration directory / workspace/.metadata directory to determine the appropriate files, then back those up.

hth.